# Removing People from Contacts Group (in Mac Address Book)

Tags: macos, applescript, contacts, addressbook

This is my first post in stackoverflow. I've spent weeks trying to get an Applescript to remove people from established Groups (not Smart Groups) in Contacts (Mac Address Book). The script removes several people then issues an error. If I re-run the script after the error is issued, it will remove a few more people from the group and then issue the same error again. I can continue doing this until eventually everyone is removed from the group. I don't understand why the error is issued when re-running the script after the error is issued results in a few more people being removed before the error is issued again. - And again, I can continue re-running the script until eventually every person is removed from the group. This suggests the contact records are not corrupted.

I've tried moving the SAVE command around but that didn't help. The Group I'm removing contacts from is labeled "Family".

The error issued is... 
error "Contacts got an error: Can’t get group \"Family\"." number -1728 from group "Family"

```
tell application "Contacts"
    set group_list to name of every group

    repeat with anItem in group_list
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
        repeat 1 times
            if first item of anItem is not "$" then exit repeat

            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "$"
            set gruppe to text item 2 of anItem
            if group gruppe exists then

                --remove every person from group
                repeat with person_to_remove in every person in group gruppe
                    set firstName to first name of every person in group gruppe
                    set group_count to count every person in group gruppe
                    remove person_to_remove from group gruppe
                    save
                end repeat

            end if

        end repeat

    end repeat
    save
    return "Done"
end tell
```

Comment: where does this error occur on the script ?

Comment: The error occurs on line "remove person_to_remove from group gruppe" in the script. Applescript Editor highlights that line and issues the following error...error "Contacts got an error: Can’t get group \"Family\"." number -1728 from group "Family".              What's odd is that if I rerun the script (after the error was issued), the script removes additional people from the group before erroring out again. If I re-run the script several times, it eventually removes everyone from the group. If there's a problem with a contact record, why does it eventually remove all people?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to hard. There is no need to change applescripts text item delimiters you can still find out if the group has a $ a the beginning of the group name

creating a 1 time loop is just weird not sure why you chose to do it that way.

you know the group already exists because you are looping through them so no need for that either

so here it is

```
tell application "Contacts"
    set group_list to name of every group

    repeat with aGroup in group_list
        if first item of aGroup is "$" then
            set thePeople to every person in group aGroup

            repeat with aPerson in thePeople
                remove aPerson from group aGroup
            end repeat

        end if
    end repeat
    save
end tell
```

Comment: THANK YOU, MCGRAILM! It worked! I'm new to scripting but learning from google, youtube and pros like you. The rest of my script (not shown here) copies people from smart groups starting with '$' to non-smart groups...hence the delimiter. The non-smart groups then sync via iCloud to iPhone and iPad. One thing I did notice is when I create a non-smart group in Contacts via AppleScript, I have to include "save" and "delay 10" seconds to script before adding people to the group...otherwise newly added people disappear from new group after 10 seconds. Is there another command I should use instead?

Comment: My point about the delimiter is that it can read the first charcater without changing the the delimiters , just remember to set them back when you are done. i typically store them in a var so i can set them back like set tid to applescript's text items delimiters

Comment: Hi there. Being new to this forum, this will be my first time accepting. Where/how do I do that? I've looked and looked but don't see an ACCEPT or similar button. LOL. Thanks!  :)